# toggle between hidden images and text using target in jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle, target

I have page for 4 projects. They are apple, banana, orange and pear. I would like to click their titles on the list in order to toggle their images and texts respectively. For example: when I click "apple" on the list, the images belong to #imageapple in the .imagebox, and the text with id #textapple should only be shown, and the url in the window gets a new hash #apple. When I click the title orange, it only shows the #imageorange and #textorange, and the url in the window gets the hash #orange . I was trying target, attr and not in Jquery but my code does not work.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function(){
      $('.title').click(function(){
        $('.imagebox').not('#image' + $(this).attr('target')).hide();
        $('#image' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
        $('.text').not('#text' + $(this).attr('target')).hide();
        $('#text' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
        window.location.hash = target;
      });
   });
```

```css
nav{
  width: 10%;
  index:999;
  padding-left: 1vh;
  flex:1;
  flex-basis: 18%;
  overflow: none;
}

nav > ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  color:black;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2vh;
}
li:hover {
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content{
  flex:1;
  flex-basis: 82%;
  display: flex;
}


.imagebox{
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  left:0;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.imagebox img{
  width: 100%;
}
.text {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-right: 2vh;
  margin-left:2vh;
  width: 30%;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Kexin Hao</title>
</head>
<body>

  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="title" target="apple">APPLE</li>
        <li class="title" target="banana">BANANA</li>
        <li class="title" target="orange"> ORANGE</li>
        <li class="title" target="pear">PEAR</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

[jsfiddle link below](https://jsfiddle.net/myd1n4e0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand 100%, but i have something that might help.

Firstly, there are a few issues with what you have.
In the HTML you need to define an imagebox element, where the image will be displayed( Correct me if i am wrong ) and I have added this.
Also there is a crash on the line `window.location.hash = target;` which is trying to redirect to the image file source it seems, but the target element needs to be resolved( See code attached ).

I made the image selection code a little more simple, and now when a link is clicked the target is resolved(Apple/banana/orange/pear), and the image is selected and added to the imagebox.
The idea would be the same for text.

Here is the HTML / JQuery I used( Image names might be slightly different on your system )

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
 <title>Kexin Hao</title>
 <script>
  $(function(){
    $('.title').click(function()
    {
   var ClickedTarget = $(this).attr('target');
   $(".imagebox").attr("src",ClickedTarget+".jpg");
     
 
    });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="title" target="apple">APPLE</li>
        <li class="title" target="banana">BANANA</li>
        <li class="title" target="orange"> ORANGE</li>
        <li class="title" target="pear">PEAR</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <img class ='imagebox'>   </img>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note you need to copy the snippet and run locally, the images files arent online.